# jQuery Image Gallery w/ Thumbnails and Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, thumbnails, lightbox

I'm looking for a jQuery image gallery with horizontal thumbnails and lightbox. Basically, something that looks like Steam workshop's image gallery: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=481123887

I found something similar but it doesn't have the lightbox (full zoom) capability: http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://fotorama.io/. For fullscreen see http://fotorama.io/customize/fullscreen/. Not quite a lightbox though, but maybe it will fit your needs.

Comment: I had to customize it a bit but it has all the features I need. Thank you!